# Confusing with principalId in loopback Rolemapping

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs, roles, loopback

Confused with the  `principalId` in Rolemapping. 
How to save it in the mongoDb . string or ObjectId.

Which is the correct method for saving it ?

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5d65f6efed4198ce6bc70d58"),
"principalType" : "USER",
"principalId" : ObjectId("5d65f6e9ed4198ce6bc70d57"),
"roleId" : ObjectId("5c74dbc3fe56e53b13b04fd7")
}
```

OR

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5d65f6efed4198ce6bc70d58"),
"principalType" : "USER",
"principalId" :"5d65f6e9ed4198ce6bc70d57",
"roleId" : ObjectId("5c74dbc3fe56e53b13b04fd7")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct method to save it is with ObjectId. As the table it is referencing will be having _id that is always a ObjectId default.

ObjectId, Number, String, and Buffer are valid for use as references. However, you should use ObjectId unless you are an advanced user and have a good reason for doing so.

Also if you want to populate this field(principalId), it also becomes easy if you have saved it with ObjectId.

Comment: Thank You.  But some search result showing, save as string. Some showing ObjectId. Is it any difference between them for using ACL ?